# Comet for User based Notification over a Message Queue

Tags: python, comet, amqp, tornado, orbited

We trying to build application that should use Comet (AJAX Push) to send notifications to individual users. Most notifications will have a fairly low timeout.

As we are running RabbitMQ, it would be easiest to send messages through AMQP. I am wondering what the best way to address individual users is, so that both the Comet server and the queue server have an easy job.

I have looked at a number of solutions including using
[Carrot](http://github.com/ask/carrot) with Orbited, Tornado, and more.

If the comet server registers one consumer (with the queue) for every user, then these consumers either have to be kept with a timeout, or discarded after every use. Neither solution seems very promising. I imagine something like this would be possible in Tornado/Carrot:

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    def get(self):
        user_id = 123

        consumer = Consumer(connection=conn, queue="feed", exchange="feed", routing_key=user_id)
        consumer.register_callback(self.message_received)
        consumer.wait()

    def message_received(self, message_data, message):
        self.write(simplejson.dumps(message_data))
        message.ack()
        consumer.close()

        self.finish()
```

Alternatively, the comet server could only have one consumer for the queue and have to implement its own lightweight message queue that can cache incoming notifications until a user connects and uses them. This seems like something that memcached might be good for, but I have no experience with it.

What would be the best approach here?

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same use case and eventually ended up with [Socket.IO](http://www.socket.io) for client-side, [TornadIO](https://github.com/MrJoes/tornadio) for handling connections and RabbitMQ for message passing (via [pika](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html)). Works quite well, worth to try it out.